# Como colocar el elemento que tenga el focus que muevo con las flechas de un listbox en un entry en tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, app, desarrollo

Estoy haciendo un buscador con autocompletar que al mover el focus de los elementos con las flechas estos se muestran en un entry, el problema es que al mover la flecha abajo se muestra el elemento anterior al que tiene el focus y al mover la flecha arriba igual se muestra un elemento atrasado al focus. Como puedo solucionar este problema?
Que el que tenga el focus sea el que aparesca en el entry

Comment: Recuerda mostrar un [repro] del problema en cuestión. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.